# Rails Rspec Expect Response Text - Not matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a PagesController, with a robots method.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def robots
          respond_to :text
          expires_in 6.hours, public: true
    end
    ...
end
```

The matching view: robots.text.erb

```
<% if !ENVied.BLOCK_ROBOTS %>
User-agent: *
Disallow:
<% else %>
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
<% end %>
```

This is working as expected when tested by hand, however, I’m having some trouble writing a test..

```
RSpec.describe PagesController, type: :controller do
...
    describe "Staging, Test and Development environments" do
             it "should generate a robots.txt that disallows access to everything." do
                ENV['BLOCK_ROBOTS']='true'
                get :robots, params: {format: "text"}

                expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to include 'text/plain'
                expect(response.body).to eq("User-Agent: * Disallow: /")
             end
    end
...
end
```

The expected output should be:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

However, the error being returned is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to eq("User-Agent: * Disallow: /")
       expected: "User-Agent: * Disallow: /"
            got: ""

       (compared using ==)
```

Commenting out the second expect statement, and only having the `expect(response.header…` statement is passing.

Manually navigating to /robots.txt is producing the desired result, so I believe I have an issue with my second expect statement.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Rails 5
Ruby 2.3.1

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '3.5.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use either

```
request.accept = "text/plain"
```

before calling `get :robots` or change the way you specify format:

```
get :robots, { format: :text }
```